Any critique of a Platonic Realm of mathematical objects?
Did any philosopher ever published a detailed criticism the idea of a Platonic Realm of mathematical objects or entities as ridiculously inflated, along the lines of Bertrand Russell's famous criticism of the Meinongian "menagerie"?
Thank you for any scholarly reference.

You mean like Aristotle's? "Also there will be several "patterns," and hence Forms, of the same thing; e.g. "animal" and "two-footed" will be patterns of "man," and so too will the Idea of Man. Further, the Forms will be patterns not only of sensible things but of themselves (e.g. genus in the sense of genus of species), and thus the same thing will be both pattern and copy." Metaphysics, 991a

@Conifold Now, that is impressive! Very interesting, thanks. I hoped for something more like 19th  or 20th century. You know, "modern" logicians?

Popper's 'The Open Society & It's Enemies' critiques Plato's political thought, but in doing that also takes aim at his 'methodological essentialism' & historicism, as bolstered by his Forms. Mathematical Platonism is still widespread, maybe follow the links on say the IEP article on the topic. You might also like this discussion: 'The Unreasonable Ineffectiveness of Mathematics in most sciences' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92058/the-unreasonable-ineffectiveness-of-mathematics-in-most-sciences/92064#92064

At the risk of repeating myself, Abraham Robinson offered a cogent critique of mathematical platonism (and endorsement of its alternative, mathematical formalism) in a series of philosophical articles in the 1960s and 70s.  You may want to consult them:

Robinson, Abraham.  Formalism 64.  Logic, Methodology and Philos. Sci. (Proc. 1964 Internat. Congr.), pp. 228–246, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1965.


Robinson, Abraham.  From a formalist's point of view. Dialectica 23 (1969), no. 1, 45-49.


Robinson, Abraham.  Concerning progress in the philosophy of mathematics. Logic Colloquium '73 (Bristol, 1973), pp. 41–52, Stud. Logic Found. Math., Vol. 80, North-Holland, Amsterdam-Oxford, 1975.

You may also be interested in a related paper by Paul Cohen and Reuben Hersh:

Cohen, Paul J.; Hersh, Reuben.  Non-Cantorian set theory.  Scientific American 217 (1967), no. 6, 104-117.

There is also a rather fierce article by Kreisel attacking both Cohen and Robinson:

Kreisel, Georg.  Observations on popular discussions
of foundations.  In Axiomatic Set Theory (Proc. Sympos. Pure
Math., Vol. XIII, Part I, Univ. California, Los Angeles, Calif.,
1967), pp. 189–198 Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., XIII, Part I.
American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1971.


What is this article by Kreisel? I need to learn fierce.

@Speakpigeon: I added the reference.
